# ExtJS Validations

Tags: extjs

How to write all validations (Vtypes) in separate Js file

vtypes for phone nos ,datefields and emails

thanq 2 all
i have write separate file with some common validation

regards

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean? Or give some example code?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?? you are asking the same question again and again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830364/extjs-gridpanel-selection-modal

Answer (score 1):

Custom VTypes can be done easily with a few simple steps:

- Apply a custom object to `Ext.form.Vtypes`
- Include the file that does the above in your page
- Use your VType like any other field

More specifically:

```
//Seperate file, validation.js
Ext.apply(Ext.form.Vtypes, {
    YOUR_V_TYPE_NAMEText: "Invalid!", //optional, a message to show when the field is invalid
    YOUR_V_TYPEMask: /.*/ //optional, a regular expression for which characters cannot be included
    YOUR_V_TYPE: function(value) {
        return false; //some expression which evaluates to true or false to validate your field
    }
});


//Your main file, main.html
//other javasript
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
```

All you need to do is replace `YOUR_V_TYPE` with the actual name of your vtype, and when you create your field, set its `vtype` property to your vtype.

Several validation types are natively supported, but if you want to create one for phone numbers or email addresses, I would strongly suggest using a regular expression. There is a large library of these [available from the Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/)